# Psycopg2 Python Inserting List

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to insert a list into the SQL query via psycopg2 but every time it see's a ' it doubles it...

heres the code:

```
for Line in ListFile:
    if CountLigne == 1:
        IDList = "'" + (Line[1].replace('"', '')) + "', "
        CountLigne += 1
    elif CountLigne < NbrLigne:
        IDList += "'" + (Line[1].replace('"', '')) + "', "
        CountLigne += 1
    else:
        IDList += (Line[1].replace('"', '') + "'")

    break
print(IDList)
print(type(IDList))
FTDSQL = (
'''WITH ftd AS (
    SELECT m.event_user, m.event_ts, m.revenue, rank() OVER (PARTITION BY            m.event_user ORDER BY m.event_ts) as order_purchase
    FROM agg_monetization m
    WHERE revenue is not null
)
SELECT distinct ftd.event_user, SUM(ftd.revenue)
FROM ftd
WHERE order_purchase = 1
AND ftd.event_user IN (%s)
GROUP BY ftd.event_user, ftd.event_ts
'''
)
Cursor.execute(FTDSQL, [IDList])
print(Cursor.query)
```

the list: '849cf768-41ea-4ed0-9861-779369d3eede', '10ad8dca-b4e6-4be5-93d3-b7fb88b1668a'

the result : AND ftd.event_user IN ('''849cf768-41ea-4ed0-9861-779369d3eede'', ''10ad8dca-b4e6-4be5-93d3-b7fb88b1668a'', ''863c3eaf-d98d-4f6a-bb97-8756750e7a09''

Thanks !!

Comment: But the list is 2964 long and will change everytime I do the query.. how can I resolve that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pyscopg2 automatically converts tuples to sql list. Take a look on [Adaptation of Python values to SQL types](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#adaptation-of-python-values-to-sql-types). So you need just to change list to tuple and then pass it.

```
FTDSQL = '''
  WITH ftd AS (
    SELECT 
      m.event_user, m.event_ts, m.revenue, 
      rank() OVER (PARTITION BY m.event_user ORDER BY m.event_ts) as order_purchase
    FROM agg_monetization m
    WHERE revenue is not null
  )
  SELECT
    distinct ftd.event_user, SUM(ftd.revenue)
  FROM ftd
  WHERE
    order_purchase = 1
  AND
    ftd.event_user IN %s
    -- parenthesis should be added automatically 
  GROUP BY ftd.event_user, ftd.event_ts
'''
)
Cursor.execute(FTDSQL, (tuple(IDList),))
```

btw on the other hand Python lists by default are converted to postgres ARRAY